# How to manually create exception with message and backtrace

Tags: ruby, exception

How can I create an exception with backtrace?

I know we could do something like this to achieve this:

```
begin
  raise StandardError, "message"
rescue StandardError => exception
  exception.backtrace
end
```

Or

```
exception = StandardError.new("message")
exception.set_backtrace(caller)
```

But I am looking for something like this:

```
exception = StandardError.new("message", backtrace: caller)
```

Is there a way that I can initialize an exception with customized message and backtrace?

Answer (score 33):

You can't initialize an exception with a backtrace, but you can assign one right after initialization.

```
exception = StandardError.new("message")
exception.set_backtrace(caller)
```

Answer (score 6):

Wrap in an functional class by yourself:

```
class ErrorCreator
  def self.new(error, message = nil, backtrace: caller)
    exception = error.new(message)
    exception.set_backtrace(backtrace)
    exception
  end
end
```

Use:

```
ErrorCreator.new(StandardError, "failed")
ErrorCreator.new(StandardError, "failed", backtrace: caller)
```

I created a gem for anyone to use: https://github.com/JuanitoFatas/active_error.

Answer (score 4):

Along the lines of the other answers, you will need to use `set_backtrace` on the error object. But you can do this in the initialize method of a custom error like so:

```
class MyError < StandardError
  def initialize(message, backtrace)
    super(message)
    set_backtrace backtrace
  end
end
```

This way you can encapsulate all your logic in a single class without needing an error factory.

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own exceptions like this :

Create a file in `app > exceptions > name_exception.rb`

name_exception.rb

```
class NameException < StandardError
  def initialize(message, backtrace)
    super
    backtrace
  end
end
```

Then in your file

```
raise NameException.new(message, backtrace)
```

You can adapt it to your needs but the pattern is here.